# Handle multiple parameters from URL in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset, url-parameters

In my app I am trying to make query on multiple parameters from the URL which is something like the following:

```
/allot-graph/?sc=Infac%20India%20Pvt.ltd&type=FLC
```

there are 2 parameters `sc` and `type`

at times they can be empty as well

I was handling the single parameter like the following:

```
class AllotmentbyMonth(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        q = 0
        try:
            q = request.GET['sc']
        except:
            pass

        if q == 0:

            print("q", q)

            dataset = Allotment.objects.all().annotate(
                month=TruncMonth('dispatch_date')).values(
                'month').annotate(c=Sum('flows__alloted_quantity')).values('month', 'c')
        else:
            print("q")
            client = Client.objects.filter(client_name = q)[0].pk
            print("client", client)
            dataset = Allotment.objects.filter(sales_order__owner=client).annotate(
                month=TruncMonth('dispatch_date')).values(
                'month').annotate(c=Sum('flows__alloted_quantity')).values('month', 'c')


        date = list(dataset)
        months = list()
        for i in date:
            months.append(i['month'].strftime("%B"))

        chart = {'chart': {'type': 'column', 'height': 400},

                 'title': {'text': 'Allotments by Months'},
                 'xAxis': {'categories': months},
                 'yAxis': {"title": {"text": 'Count'}},

                 'series': [{'name': 'Months', 'data': [{'name': row['month'], 'y': row["c"]} for row in dataset]}]}

        print("chart", chart)

        return Response(chart)
```

I know it's not the ideal way but this was my workaround. How can I handle the filter `type` in this as writing too many `if-else` just doesn't seem right.

The filter for `type` is this :

```
.filter(flows__kit__kit_type = type)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`.get(...)`** method as

```
class AllotmentbyMonth(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        qp_sc = request.query_params.get("sc")
        qp_type = request.query_params.get("type")

        client_qs = Client.objects.all()
        if qp_sc:
            client_qs = client_qs.filter(some_field_name=qp_sc)
```

Since you are using DRF, it is good to use [**`request.query_params`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params) instead of `request.GET`

Comment: what if I have both `sc` and `type`?